# How to use SearchBar for API's?

Tags: ios, swift

```
 // MARK: - Search

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        if self.searchController.searchBar.text!.characters.count < 3 {
            print("<3")
        }else{
        Kinopoisk.searchFilmByString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!) { (JSON) in
            for index in 0...5 {
                let nameRU = JSON["searchFilms"][index]["nameRU"].string ?? ""
                let nameEN = JSON["searchFilms"][index]["nameEN"].string ?? ""
                let plusString = "\(nameRU)/\(nameEN)"
                self.movies.append(plusString)
                print(self.movies[index])
            }
        }
        }
        self.filteredMovies = self.movies.filter { (movie: String) -> Bool in
            if movie.lowercaseString.containsString(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

[image]

I have two arrays(movies and filteredMovies). The first recorded data from JSON (API), the second contained sorted data from first array.

**Problem 1:**
When I start to enter searchBar's field starts downloading from API to first array, but if i add new character to field old data will stay.
How delete data in first array after search request?

**Problem 2:**
API have limit for search by >2 character - How to start search only when there is more than two symbols in SearchBar.text?

**Problem 3:**
Search start only when i deselect from enter. - How to search while you type rather than after?

Comment: add code to your question . Please dont post code as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to do things right, you should use a reactive framework. Most people are hot on ReactiveCocoa right now, but a lot of people also use RxSwift. I am more of a RAC guy so I will point you in that direction.

[Colin Eberhardt](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt) wrote a [blog post](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/05/15/mvvm-reactive-cocoa-3.html) about making an [app](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveTwitterSearch) that does basically this exact thing with twitter searching. He also has another similar [RAC flickr app](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/ReactiveSwiftFlickrSearch). He uses RAC3 which is only slightly different (mostly syntax changes) from RAC4. I would highly suggest learning about and beginning to implement Functional Reactive techniques in your apps.

Cheers!